# Mouse stops working while installing 13.04 and 12.04 in 64-bit, but 32-bit works

Tags: system-installation, mouse, 64-bit, ram, 32-bit

I've just bought a new desktop computer:

- Gigabyte 970A-DS3
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 650
- AMD FX8350
- RAM: 16 GB

I'd like to install 13.04 64-bit, but when I try to install it, the mouse doesn't work at all (via PS2, USB and Wireless). The same thing happens on 12.04 64-bit.

However, on 12.04 32-bit, it works fine.

My question is: What version should I install? If I install 32-bit, will I be able to use the full RAM and full capacities? Is it better for me to wait for 13.10 64-bit?

Answer (score 0):

Your better off install 64bit version of 13.04 and finding out why your mouse doesn't work. Does it work on the live CD? Can you show us log output from Xorg.log or `dmesg`.

Start with wired mice, and work up to wireless mice. What type of mouse/mice are you tryng to use? Almost every PS/2 mouse works but I don't even know where you would buy one any more. Could it be that your PS/2 Mouse it to old?

Start by making sure the kernel sees you mouse. Check in /var/log/messages for any errors. Then see if X sees your mouse. /var/log/Xorg.log should have lines starting with EE if there are any problems.

Comment: Thank you coteyr. I've done what you told me and I've made some tests. Finally, I'm installing 13.04 64-bit at this moment. It recognices USB devices switched in USB 3 port. So I've switched the wireless mouse and the wi-fi adapter. Once it is installed I tell if I can make USB 2 ports work. Thanks again.